# How do I handle digits in a reverse polish notation calculator?

Tags: java, postfix-notation

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;


public class PostFixEval {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String expression;
    static Stack<Integer> calcStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    static List<String> expressionList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static boolean flag = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter Your Expression: ");
        while (flag == false){
            expression = input.next();
            System.out.println("");
            expression = whiteSpaceRemover(expression);

            if (expression.substring(expression.length() - 1) == ";"){
                expressionList.add(expression);
            } else if (expression.substring(expression.length() - 1) == "@"){
                expressionList.add(expression);
                flag = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a valid expression (must end in a ; or a @)");
            }
        }

        calc(expressionList);               
    }

    public static void calc(List<String> list){
        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            String currentExpression = list.get(i);

            for (char ch : currentExpression.toCharArray()){
                if (ch == '+'){
                    calcStack.push(calcStack.pop()+calcStack.pop());

                    System.out.println("Pop R1");
                    System.out.println("Pop R2");
                    System.out.println("ADD R1, R2");
                    System.out.println("PUSH R1");
                } 
                else if (ch == '-')
                {
                    int temp = calcStack.pop();
                    calcStack.push(calcStack.pop() - temp);

                    System.out.println("Pop R2");
                    System.out.println("Pop R1");
                    System.out.println("SUB R1, R2");
                    System.out.println("PUSH R1");
                } 
                else if (ch == '*')
                {
                    calcStack.push(calcStack.pop() * calcStack.pop());

                    System.out.println("Pop R1");
                    System.out.println("Pop R2");
                    System.out.println("MULT R1, R2");
                    System.out.println("PUSH R1");
                } 
                else if (ch == '/')
                {
                    int temp = calcStack.pop();

                    if(temp != 0){
                        calcStack.push(calcStack.pop() / temp);
                        System.out.println("Pop R1");
                        System.out.println("Pop R2");
                        System.out.println("DIV R1, R2");
                        System.out.println("PUSH R1");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("CANNOT DIVIDE BY ZERO");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if
                {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(ch);
                }


            }
        }

    }

    public static String whiteSpaceRemover(String express){
        return express.replaceAll(" ","");
    }

}
```

I've been working on a Reverse Polish Notation calculator, but I've ran into a problem. I've realised I can't add the numbers to the stack as my code goes through each character of each expression individually. I've thought about adding each number to an array and then converting that to a int, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As you are eqyating string then `if (expression.substring(expression.length() - 1) == ";"){` should be `if (";".equals(expression.substring(expression.length() - 1))){`

Comment: I found one more mistake You forgot to specify condition for `if ` statement `else if (Some condtion) {  int num = Integer.parseInt(ch); }`

Comment: `calcStack.push(calcStack.pop() + calcStack.pop());` You cant do this. `calcStack.pop()` this statement cant fetch anything because at that point your stack is completely empty throwing `EmptyStackException`.

Comment: This isn't completed code, the reason why there is no if statement condition is because I'm not sure how to get each number for the equation onto the stack.

Comment: For example a input may be 12 2 + 2 -@ should evaluate to (12+2)-2 = 12 but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: if you can use something else than char (I found it clumsy for your situation), then I will suggest to separate the expression by using split method like `String.split(\\s+)`. It will give you array and you can use that array to build your new expression to calculate value.